# xterm is calling .cshrc twice

Tags: xterm, tcsh

The following command

```
xterm -e ' tcsh'
```

calls my .cshrc file twice.    But this command calls it once

```
xterm -e 'tcsh'
```

Same thing with

```
xterm -e 'cd `pwd`;tcsh'
```

Obviously, the only difference between the first call and the other two calls is the space.    Why would a space make such a difference?

To test this out, I'm using this MWE version of .cshrc

```
#/bin/tcsh
echo called from cshrc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 18.04, here's the output of `uname -a`: `Linux XPS 4.18.12-041812-generic #201810032137 SMP Thu Oct 4 01:39:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x`